# AutoMapper's AssertConfigurationIsValid fails on first load only?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

In X/WebSiteMVC3/Core/DependencyResolution/XProfile.cs, I have an existing mapping that looks a little something like this:

```
 CreateMap<DomainObjects.Entities.Thing1, Models.Thing1>();
 CreateMap<Models.Thing1, DomainObjects.Entities.Thing1>()
     .ForMember(a => a.Thing2, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.ModifiedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.ModifiedDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.CreatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.CreatedDate, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

And I needed to add in a mapping for its child object, so I put in this:

```
 CreateMap<DomainObjects.Entities.Thing2, Models.Thing2>();
 CreateMap<Models.Thing2, DomainObjects.Entities.Thing2>()
     .ForMember(a => a.ModifiedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.ModifiedDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.CreatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.CreatedDate, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

And it works, except on the first page load, I get this:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
>
> Thing2 -> Thing2 (Destination member list)
>
> X.X.WebSiteMVC3.Models.Thing2 -> X.X.DomainObjects.Entities.Thing2 (Destination member list)
>
> Thing1

StackTrace:

> AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable`1 typeMaps) +684
>      AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.AssertConfigurationIsValid() +12
>      AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() +23
>      X.X.WebSiteMVC3.Core.DependencyResolution.AutomapperRegistry.Configure() in C:\Source\X.X.WebSiteMVC3\Core\DependencyResolution\AutomapperRegistry.cs:13
>      X.X.WebSiteMVC3.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Source\X.X.WebSiteMVC3\Global.asax.cs:96

But on *every* other subsequent load, it works as intended!?

So... why is Thing2 failing, when its implementation matches that of Thing1 (which does work all the time)? And why is Thing1 being mentioned in the error for Thing2 (I have a feeling this is the cause, but darned if I can see it at 10am on this idle Thursday)?

Muchos Danke!

Comment: How are you calling your automapper config?  From Application_Start in global.asax.cs?

Comment: Yes, "Core.DependencyResolution.AutomapperRegistry.Configure();" is being called from Application_Start in global.asax.cs. I was at somehting of a loss on this issue thanks to this being my first MVC app of any heft, and the fact that the developer who wrote it is on vacation, so I'm a stringer (who doesn't want to change too much in the codebase thanks to my ignorance more then anything else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, this was being caused by a cross reference on Thing2 back to Thing1... so I had to do this...

```
 CreateMap<DomainObjects.Entities.Thing2, Models.Thing2>();
 CreateMap<Models.Thing2, DomainObjects.Entities.Thing2>()
 !-> .ForMember(a => a.Thing1, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.ModifiedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.ModifiedDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.CreatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ForMember(a => a.CreatedDate, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

What really struck me as odd is that the error message I was getting ("Unmapped members were found...") didn't turn up on the Google!? Normally when this occurs, I've managed to do something really weird/odd hence my quick trigger to ask a question here. Where as in this case the problem was somewhat trivial.

So... to others who may get here via the Google: this is likely something to do with your model itself rather than some oddity with AutoMapper. though I still have no clue why the mappings "worked" on a second pass!? That is just weird!

Comment: I'm getting same error.. i'm sure it's my newness with it.. at least this is a start.. thanks!